# Include withspace in split

Tags: c#

Given that I have this string,

```
string word = 'Good AM World or Good PM World';
string[] splitWord = word.Split(' or ');   <----- This line gives me an error.
```

In code above I want to split the string into two.

**Output should be**

> Good AM World
>
> Good PM World

Is there wrong in my code?. BTW i'm learning c# language.

Comment: Well, that first line should also be giving you an error, since strings are defined inside double quotes, not single quotes! :)  But what is the error message on the line that you've called out? Does it give any clues as to what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have single quotes and not double, also you need the right overload

```
string word = "Good AM World or Good PM World";
string[] splitWord = word.Split(new []{" or "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

---

[Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_)

> Splits a string into substrings based on the strings in an array. You
>   can specify whether the substrings include empty array elements.

[StringSplitOptions Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> **Fields**
>
> - `None` The return value includes array elements that contain an empty string
> - `RemoveEmptyEntries` The return value does not include array elements that contain an empty string

And for you amusement here is a [Working Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/keYnLQ)

**Output**

```
Good AM World
Good PM World
```

Answer (score 0):

`Split()` does not take `string` as parameter. Use the other overload like this:

```
var word = "Good AM World or Good PM World";
var splitWord = word.Split(new []{" or "},StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this.

```
string word = "Good AM World or Good PM World";
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] {" or "};
var result = word.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (var element in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```